# How can I use QgsRasterDataProvider.write from Python in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I would like to change a raster cell value from Python in QGIS using QgsRasterDataProvider.write method. It takes the following arguments  [(from QGIS API)](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterDataProvider.html#af15b6038b5c59276a4ef87598b919482):

```
virtual bool QgsRasterDataProvider::write   (   
    void *      data,
    int     band,
    int     width,
    int     height,
    int     xOffset,
    int     yOffset 
)
```

How can I construct the pointer (data) with the new cell value?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [post from the QGIS-developer's list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.qgis.devel/22848), you could use the following which directly uses the `QgsRasterDataProvider`:

```
QgsRasterDataProvider * provider = ( QgsRasterDataProvider*)QgsProviderRegistry::instance()->provider( "gdal", dataSource );
provider->write( data, band, width, height, xOffset, yOffset )
```

Comment: Joseph, there is no problem in C++ but how to define the _data_ pointer in **Python**?

Comment: @RadekPasiok - Apologies, not sure how I missed that but I don't work with rasters much. Can't find much information regarding `QgsRasterDataProvider.write`, there is a post [here](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.co.uk&sl=es&u=https://joseguerreroa.wordpress.com/2016/02/21/como-modificar-individualmente-los-valores-de-un-raster-en-qgis-con-python/&usg=ALkJrhhhtWX8JzzmaUs6pHopO9PU55yfAw) (translated) which describes an alternative method which _may_ be helpful.

Comment: Joseph, thanks for the link - this is how I do it currently using GDAL, see https://github.com/erpas/serval/blob/master/serval_widget.py.